# Firestore pricing clarifications for offline cached data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It seems odd to me that Firestore would charge me for read queries to locally cached data, but I can't find any clarification to the contrary in the [Firestore Pricing document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing). If I force Firebase into offline mode and then perform reads on my locally cached data, am I still charged for each individual entity that I retrieve?

Second, offline users in my app write many small updates to a single entity. I want the changes to persist locally each time (in case they quit the app), but I only need eventually consistent saves to the cloud. When a user reconnects to the internet and Firestore flushes the local changes, will I be charged a single write request for the entity or one per `update` call that I made while offline?

Firestore could potentially fit my use case very well, but if offline reads and writes are charged at the same rate as online ones it would not be an affordable option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) says,

> Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the data stored remotely in Cloud Firestore.

So, every client that is using a Firestore database and sets `PersistenceEnabled` to true, maintains it's own internal (local) version of the database. When data is inserted/updated, it is first written to this local version of the database. As a result, all writes to the database are added to a `queue`. This means that all the operations that where stored there will be commited on Firebase servers once you are back online. This also means that those operations will be seen as independent operations and not as a whole.

But remeber, don't use Firestore as an offline-only database. It is really designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. While offline it will keep queue of write operations. As this queue grows, local operations and app startup will slow down. Nothing major, but over time these may add up.

If `Google Cloud Firestore` priceing model does not fit your use case very well then use `Firebase Realtime Database`. As mentioned also in this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html) from the Firebase offical blog, one the reasons you still might want to use the Realtime Database is:

> As we noted above, Cloud Firestore's pricing model means that applications that perform very large numbers of small reads and writes per second per client could be significantly more expensive than a similarly performing app in the Realtime Database.

So it's up to you which option you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It makes sense on the writes that Firestore would replay the transactions in order since it is intended to be an online-first datastore (rather than offline-first like Pouch or Realm). Do you know the answer to whether local reads are priced the same as network reads?
I might play around with keeping my own local cache that I can flush to Firestore periodically, but for now I will consider this question answered

Comment: I understand that but Firestore is first desined as an online database. Cheers!

Comment: @AndyMiller The accepted answer doesn't really answer your question 'Whether we are charged for local cache data query'. It gives many other useful information though.

Did you find the answer?

Comment: @NishanthSreedhara You are not charged for local cache data query but when you'll get back online, every operation that is in the queue will be charged as separate write operation.

Comment: Does this answer mean that my app can always rely on having an up to date copy of some version of the data (cached or cloud), or does the data get purged from cache when there are no listeners?

Comment: Yes it does. No, the data remains in the cache even if you you stop listening for changes. The cache will be deleted only if you do it manually or if you unintstall the app.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#disableNetwork) If you want to work completely offline with Cloud Firestore you can disable network by :

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().disableNetwork()
```

but firestore will cause client offline error for first user get request, that you must consider this error as empty response.

Comment: Where do you see anything about an error response there?

Comment: In addOnFailureListener of Task<DocumentSnapshot> class, get() method of DocumentReference returns an object of Task<DocumentSnapshot> type.

Comment: He's not asking how to do it, you didn't read the questions.