# Firestore costs & (offline) cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding the costs of Firestore's read operations.

When a client performs multiple read operations on the same document while it has not been changed in any way **and the device is online**, will I be charged for every read operation or will the document be served from a local cache for the second and subsequent reads?

Is there a difference in the behaviour when the device is online vs. offline given offline cache is enabled?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore pricing clarifications for offline cached data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178737/firestore-pricing-clarifications-for-offline-cached-data)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question. I would still like to know if multiple reads to the same **unchanged** document will be charged individually when the device is **ONLINE** or if this counts as one read?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687303/10810527) by Doug Stevenson where he explains that the reads are only charged performed upon **the server**, not your **local cache**.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot of things :) If you add this as an answer to my question I can and will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687303/10810527) by Doug Stevenson, the reads are only charged when performed upon the server, not your local cache. That is if the local persistence is enabled on your client (it is by default) and the documents haven't been updated in the server.

Regarding the offline requests, in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47179668/10810527) there's an explanation that everything works *the same* in offline mode because it will keep using the data in the local cache. As we explained on the first answer, this is not charged.