# Android Application with firebase connectivty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I create an android application which has firebase connection for database services, then is it necessary to have a internet connection to run and use the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important feature of Firebase Realtime Database is by far, the real-time feature. This means that you can stay in sync with the Firebase servers, to always get real-time updates. However, if there is no internet connection on the user's device, Firebase provides another very useful feature which is [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). As in the official documentation, to enable this feature, you should simply use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

But remember, this feature works for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. If you want to use an offline-only database, you might consider using a local database. For that I recommend you using the [Room Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

Comment: Thanks for the brief description dear! I going to develop a application in android which is light weighted means it should consume little amount of memory and retrieval of data from database is easier and faster so guide me what database i should use?

Comment: You can use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) depending on the use-case of your app. Here are some [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178737/firestore-pricing-clarifications-for-offline-cached-data).

Comment: Thanks for the relative and descriptive answer dear I really appreciate it thanks again